# Would I have some areas with underdeveloped muscles only practicing powerlifting?

Tags: powerlifting

I do only these four  exercises in the gym: Barbell row, Benchpress, squats, romanian deadlifts.., and very rarely, some over headpresses. To my understanding, these are also the core exercises of those who wish to do powerlifting. My question is, would doing only these exercises lead to some under development in the total physique?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are all compound exercises which employ multiple muscles for each muscle. That being said I beleive the biggest deficit would be in you shoulder. Bench press incorporates shoulders slightly but only the front delts. The the rest of the shoulders will end up under-developed. Also I'm assuming you are referring to a flat bench so your upper chest may become slightly under-developed too.

Comment: My weekly pressing include three flat bench variations, an incline bench, and standing overhead press. Obviously I like pressing a lot, but  a one flat, one incline, one standing press schedule would cover all your bases pretty well.